# How to fix Coreplot Pie Chart Problems in 64 bit version vs 32 bit version

Tags: ios, 32bit-64bit, core-plot

The h file for the relevant view controller

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "StudentModel.h"
#import "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h"


@interface AttendenceViewController : UIViewController     <UITabBarDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,CPTLegendDelegate,CPTPieChartDataSource,CPTPieChartDelegate>

@property (strong,nonatomic) StudentModel *studentA;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSDictionary *studentAttendanceDetails;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *graphContainer;
```

The m file for the relevant view controller

```
#import "AttendenceViewController.h"

@interface AttendenceViewController ()
@property (nonatomic,strong) CPTGraphHostingView *hostView;
@property (nonatomic,strong) CPTTheme *selectedTheme;

-(void)initPlot;
-(void)configureHost;
-(void)configureGraph;
-(void)configureChart;
-(void)configureLegend;
@end

@implementation AttendenceViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
//    float attendanceTotal = [self.studentA.percentageAttendance floatValue];
//    float authorisedAbsences = [self.studentA.authorisedAbsences floatValue];
//    float unathorisedAbsences = [self.studentA.unautherisedAbsences floatValue];

self.studentAttendanceDetails = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:self.studentA.percentageAttendance,@"totalAttendance",self.studentA.authorisedAbsences,@"authorisedAbsences",self.studentA.unautherisedAbsences,@"unauthorisedAbsences", nil];
NSLog(@"%@",self.studentAttendanceDetails);
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
[self initPlot];

}

#pragma mark Core Plot Initialisation Methods
-(void)initPlot
{
[self configureHost];
[self configureGraph];
[self configureChart];
[self configureLegend];

}

-(void)configureHost;
{
CGRect parentRect = self.graphContainer.bounds;
self.hostView = [(CPTGraphHostingView*)[CPTGraphHostingView alloc]initWithFrame:parentRect];
self.hostView.allowPinchScaling=NO;
[self.graphContainer addSubview:self.hostView];
}
-(void)configureGraph;
{
//create and initialise the graph
CPTGraph *graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc]initWithFrame:self.hostView.bounds];
self.hostView.hostedGraph=graph;
graph.paddingLeft=0.0f;
graph.paddingTop=0.0f;
graph.paddingRight=0.0f;
graph.paddingBottom=0.0f;
graph.axisSet=nil;
//set up the text styles
CPTMutableTextStyle *textStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
textStyle.color= [CPTColor grayColor];
textStyle.fontName =@"Helvetica-Bold";
textStyle.fontSize=16.0f;
//configure the title
NSString *title = @"Student Attendance";
graph.title=title;
graph.titleTextStyle=textStyle;
graph.titlePlotAreaFrameAnchor= CPTRectAnchorTop;
graph.titleDisplacement= CGPointMake(0.0f, -12.0f);
self.selectedTheme = [CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTPlainWhiteTheme];
[graph applyTheme:self.selectedTheme];

}
-(void)configureChart;
{
//get reference to graph
CPTGraph *graph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;
//create chart
CPTPieChart *pieChart = [[CPTPieChart alloc]init];
pieChart.delegate=self;
pieChart.dataSource=self;
pieChart.pieRadius=(self.hostView.bounds.size.height*0.9)/3;
pieChart.identifier= graph.title;
pieChart.startAngle = M_PI_4;
pieChart.sliceDirection=CPTPieDirectionClockwise;
//gradient
CPTGradient *overlayGradient = [[CPTGradient alloc]init];
overlayGradient.gradientType=CPTGradientTypeRadial;
overlayGradient=[overlayGradient addColorStop:[[CPTColor blackColor]colorWithAlphaComponent:0.0] atPosition:0.9];
overlayGradient=[overlayGradient addColorStop:[[CPTColor blackColor]colorWithAlphaComponent:0.4] atPosition:1.0];
pieChart.overlayFill = [CPTFill fillWithGradient:overlayGradient];
[graph addPlot:pieChart];
}
-(void)configureLegend;
{

}


#pragma mark Core Plot Datasource Methods

-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot
{
return [self.studentAttendanceDetails count];
}

-(NSNumber*)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx
{
if (CPTPieChartFieldSliceWidth == fieldEnum)
{
    NSArray *values =  [self.studentAttendanceDetails allValues];
    return [values objectAtIndex:idx];

}
return [NSDecimalNumber zero];
}

-(CPTLayer*)dataLabelForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx
{
static CPTMutableTextStyle *labelText = nil;
if (!labelText) {
    labelText= [[CPTMutableTextStyle alloc] init];
    labelText.color = [CPTColor grayColor];
}

NSString *labelValue = nil;

switch (idx) {

    case 0:{
        NSString *unauthorised= [self.studentAttendanceDetails objectForKey:@"unauthorisedAbsences"];
        NSLog(@"%@",unauthorised);
        if ([unauthorised isEqualToString:@"0.00"]) {
            labelText=nil;
        }
        labelValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.studentAttendanceDetails objectForKey:@"unauthorisedAbsences"]];
    }
        break;

    case 1:
        labelValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.studentAttendanceDetails objectForKey:@"totalAttendance"]];
                    break;
        case 2:
        labelValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.studentAttendanceDetails objectForKey:@"authorisedAbsences"]];

        break;
            }
return [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:labelValue style:labelText];


}

-(NSString*)legendTitleForPieChart:(CPTPieChart *)pieChart recordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx
{
return @"Student Attendance";
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Image of result when simulator is set to iPhone 5 and run[image] (i.e. 32 bit)

Image of result when simulator is set to iPhone 5s or later (i.e 64bit)

[image]

The problem is how to I adjust the code in the implementation file for the view controller to ensure the output is the same for 32 bit and 64 bit runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries don't have a defined ordering. The `allValues` array is probably different on each platform. For this application, you don't need to stash the values in a dictionary at all. Just return `authorisedAbsences` or `unautherisedAbsences` from the datasource based on the index.

Comment: I will have a look at this thanks, but that would not explain why the colours the pie chart is drawn in have changed , or would it?

Comment: Yes, because implementation differences between the two platforms may put the `allValues` array in a different order. Regardless, it's not something you should rely on.